# Can I put just the hostname as serverName in apache virtualHost directive?

Tags: hostname

I am trying to configure a virtual host in Apache 2.4 on a linux box.

Assume hostname for my box is:

```
$> hostname
nyfedev01
```

and it's fqdn is

```
$> hostname --fqdn
nyfeddev01.ny.miorg.com
```

and its ip address is 10.193.91.225

Now in apache's httpd.conf file, can I specify virtualHost ServerName's value as hostname value as below?

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName nyfedev01
    DocumentRoot "path/to/files/to/serve"
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to access this in my browser as: http://nyfedev01:8000/
I want to use this URL to load a different set of files from the default url http://nyfedv01/.

Comment: yes, if you mapped in your /etc/hosts, anyway what you want to archive using short names?

Comment: Short name already works in the network (http://nyfedv01/) I wanted to add this additional virtualHost but was not sure if it will be correct to give just the hostname as ServerName. What difference will it make if I give in fqdn as ServerName instead? Will http://nyfed01:8000/ still work?

Comment: Use the FQDN as the ServerName and then whatever you want (including just the hostname) as ServerAlias(es)

Comment: This question is about HTTPD Server configuration, why on earth has it been migrated to super user?

Comment: I got no control over this migration, I was just informed that this has been moved to superuser from serverfault. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you? Well, The matter is not if you can, it is that **YOU SHOULD**.

Consider you will have more than one virtualhost, when you type a url in your browser, such as http://nyfedev01 your browser sends a specific **request header** called "**Host**", which will include nyfedev01, this is what Apache HTTPD reads to know to which virtualhost this request must be delivered, and guess where you must define this value? You guessed correctly, **ServerName**

So yes, you are very much encouraged to define the hostnames you are going to use in the servername directive of every virtualhost you are going to use, being it a local machine name, or your public url, or even an ip if you are going to call an ip in your browser.

Note: just consider name resolution is up to you, so you will have to provide the means for your http clients to be able to resolve those names correctly to point to the correct ip of the http server.

Comment: Agree the question is more about 'Should' rather than 'Can'. Rightly pointed.  

"Host" request header sent by the browser makes it clear what should go in ServerName. That was the missing piece in the puzzle about what  'should' be given as the ServerName. Thanks.